# nan output due to maclaurin series expansion of sine, console crashes

Tags: c++, math, trigonometry

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int factorial(int);

int main()
{
    for(int k = 0; k < 100000; k++)
    {
        static double sum = 0.0;
        double term;
        term = (double)pow(-1.0, k) * (double)pow(4.0, 2*k+1) / factorial(2*k+1);
        sum = sum + term;
        cout << sum << '\n';
    }
}





int factorial(int n)
{
    if(n == 0)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    return n*factorial(n-1);
}
```

I'm just trying to calculate the value of `sine(4)` using the `maclaurin` expansion form of `sine`. For each console output, the value reads '`nan`'. The console gives an error and shuts down after like 10 second. I don't get any errors in the IDE.

Comment: Do you know how big `100000!` is?

Comment: Yes, I have done more than a million before, shouldn't be getting any problems with that at all buddy

Comment: `12!` should be the biggest number you can calculate with a `int`. Do `std::cout << factorial(13)` and see if it equals `6227020800`

Comment: Ah, that could be the problem! Darn. Let me see what I can do about that, thank you

Comment: Ok, I changed the factorial function into a long double, and this time I have more numerical values showing up at start, but then the nan numbers follow... I really need to learn how to make C++ deal with numbers that exceed 2^31

Comment: *I really need to learn how to make C++ deal with numbers that exceed 2^31*  It might be better to learn how to compute Maclaurin series (etc) without resort to such numbers.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark You are partly right, but it'd really suck to not be able to do anything with very high numbers in programming, wouldn't it?

Comment: It would suck even more if you obstinately choose the more inefficient brute-force route instead applying smart optimizations in-order to utilize what you already have.

Comment: 'Obstinately', nice word. I looked up the meaning now, and no, I am not, at all, obstinate on this. I do agree that I should be trying to figure out how to optimize, but I do also want to be able to just do it fast with brute force, since I'm not a developer and I do not really care how efficient my code is going to be unless I'm going to use it a lot or it just takes way too long.

Comment: If you really insist, have a look at arbitrary precision libraries such as GMP. And please, don't make `sum` static.

Comment: Why not, I want the sum to be initialized to '0' only once and never again. The way to do that is to use a static declaration-initialization.

Comment: I don't want to be offensive here, but you seem to have a lack of very basic C++ knowledge. It's hard to start with such an advanced problem if you don't know the basics.

Initialize `sum` before the loop then it doesn't have to be static :)

Comment: So you're not going to tell me the answer of 'why not'?

Comment: To my big surprise, everyone is answering next to the question. _Why is my program exhibiting this behaviour?_ The answer is surprisingly [infinite/very deep recursion **Stack Overflow**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow#Infinite_recursion) due to the factorial.

Comment: This question might be of interest to you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50391716/small-difference-in-fortran-sine-function-using-maclaurin-expansion

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark _It might be better to learn how to compute Maclaurin series (etc) without resort to such numbers._ Guess what I've done. I created string functions that can do summation, subtraction, multiplication, and division. User enters 2 numbers, I put each of them in a string, and then I put the digits of those numbers into vectors, and then digit by digit, I do the math, and recombine the result into a string. But my functions need to be more speedy, so I've already become somewhat good about optimizing code for speed and no-error flow. I can now play with numbers of 2^31 digits.

Answer (score 1):

There're multiple problems with your approach.

Your factorial function can't return an `int`. The return value will be way too big, very quickly.

Using `pow(-1, value)` to get a alternating positive/negative one is very inefficient and will yield incorrect value pretty quick. You should pick 1.0 or -1.0 depending on k's parity.

When you sum a long series of terms, you want to sum the terms with the least magnitude first. Otherwise, you lose precision due to existing bit limiting the range you can reach. In your case, the power of four is dominated by the factorial, so you sum the highest magnitude values first. You'd probably get better precision starting by the other end.

Algorithmically, if you're going to raise 4 to the 2k+1 power and then divide by (2k+1)!, you should keep both the list of factors (4, 4, 4, 4...) and (2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,....) and simplify both sides. There's plenty of fours to remove on the numerators and denominators at the same time.

Even with those four, I'm not sure you can get anywhere close to the 100000 target you set, without specialized code.

Comment: Very valuable answer, thank you, but 2 of the 4 things you mentioned, I was not able to get. How can pow(-1, value) possibly yield a false result, unless 'value' exceeds the max number limit? I also didn't understand your second point, I don't see any reason with the knowledge I have, why the order of summation would at all affect the precision of the result, can you enlighten me on that? For me, 1 + 0.1 = 1.1 and 0.1 + 1 = 1.1, no difference

Comment: `pow(-1, value)` leads to undefined behavior according to the [C standard](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/pow/). It may be the result for `NaN`, since an integer overflow would simply wrap around.

Comment: @EmirhanG. Point 2: `pow` operates on floating point numbers. They are imprecise and bad things can happen. `k%2?-1:1` operates entirely with integers, but a simple `int x = 1;`and a `x*=-1` at the end of the loop may be faster depending on how sharp the compiler is.

Answer (score 0):

As already stated by others, the intermediate results you will get for large `k` are magnitudes too large to fit into a double. From a certain `k` on `pow` as well as `factorial` will return infinity. This is simply what happens for very large doubles. And as you then divide one infinity by another you get NaN.

One common trick to deal with too large numbers is using logarithms for intermediate results and only in the end apply the exponential function once.
Some mathematical knowledge of logarithms is required here. To understand what I am doing here you need to know `exp(log(x)) == x`, `log(a^b) == b*log(a)`, and `log(a/b) == log(a) - log(b)`.

In your case you can rewrite

```
pow(4, 2*k+1)
```

to

```
exp((2*k+1)*log(4))
```

Then there is still the factorial. The [lgamma](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/lgamma) function can help with `factorial(n) == gamma(n+1)` and `log(factorial(n)) == lgamma(n+1)`. In short, lgamma gives you the log of a factorial without huge intermediate results.

So summing up, replace

```
pow(4, 2*k+1) / factorial(2*k+1)
```

With

```
exp((2*k+1)*log(4) - lgamma(2*k+2))
```

This should help you with your NaNs. Also, this should increase performance as `lgamma` operates in `O(1)` whereas your `factorial` is in `O(k)`.

Note, however, that I have still very little confidence that your result will be numerically accurate.
A double has still limited precision of roughly 16 decimal digits. Your 100000 iterations are very likely worthless, probably even harmfull.